# app binary organization

Tags: iphone, ios

Two questions, kind of same category:

1. When I checked from Xcode, I saw a folder library/cache/imagecaches (quite some files there) on iPhone under my app, I never created that folder, I guess it it was managed by iOS itself, nothing for me to concern.
2. I have a sqlite file called app.sqlite, and it is in documents folder. that's the right place to pass app review right, right?

Comment: If you have two questions, then post two questions! Posting them as one just complicates things for people trying to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have never seen it before then it is iOS's own cache system, you shouldn't mess with it.
2. Check it out https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html